# Using a Mac in a .NET Web Services enviornment?

Tags: .net, macos, web-services, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I know this question has been asked before, but I think this has a different spin to it. At my company our application's backend and front-end are developed separately. Our Front-End is built with AngularJS receiving a RESTful endpoint from the backend. I know the general consensus is you can't develop on a Mac in a .NET environment. However what if your application just received JSON?

I'm thinking I would write the bulk of my Front-End code on my Mac. Use WebStorm or Eclipse's TFS client to check in my code. Run a local Node or Python server on my Mac for Angular to work locally but point angular's $resource method to point to our back-end.

I'm still fairly new to the .NET environment so I'm not sure how the back-end would have to be setup. Is there anything I'm missing? How would I keep the Back-End's endpoint always available without leaving a copy of Visual Studio running?

Answer (score 2):

It would work fine. Set the backend up using IIS or IIS Express.

It would mean however that your API (backend) is a completely different web app than your frontend. Sometimes this is just what you intend, a stand-alone reusable API.

Sometimes it's not what you intend, a specific API for just your web app is often easier to implement within the same application that serves the frontend code. You will have to solve CORS issues and handle authentication differently when the two are separated.

Or are you intending to serve both from a .NET server in production, just run your front-end web server locally during development? (then you'll still have to solve CORS when running on your machine).

Comment: Agreed, the question could be re-framed as "can HTML/Javascript written on a Mac consume JSON over HTTP from a windows server?"  Yes.

Comment: Yes, but if the intention is to serve the frontend files from the same server as the backend in production the question is if it would be wise. I always find that a local environment differing too much from the target environment will cause problems down the line.

Comment: Obviously I know JavaScript written on a Mac can consume JSON over HTTP regardless of the server. However in production I want them to be one application without having to deal with CORS. I should also mention that in production legacy parts of the application are still written in WebForms, so it very much needs to be one app with its current authentication scheme.